# How to unit Test for Xtext

Tags: unit-testing, dsl, xtext, xtend

I have to test my grammar (written with Xtext). I've see it is possible with use of unit test, but I can't find a good tutorial about it.

Can you help me?

Comment: A unit test verifies that some unit of code is compliant with the specification, usually beyond plain compiletime errors. What exactly do you want to *unit test*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several links about this.

- The official tutorials have chapter about special Xtext/Junit support: [Unit Testing the Language](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#TutorialUnitTests)
- [Xtext-Utils](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/xtext-utils/wiki/Unit_Testing) has some tools
- Xpect provides a DSL for unittesting DSLs. [Slides here](http://www.slideshare.net/meysholdt/testdriven-development-of-xtext-dsls#btnNext) (Looks interesting)
- The slides of Markus Voelter "[Testing DSLs](http://www.voelter.de/data/presentations/oop2012-dslTesting-slides.pdf)" explain stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Xpect seems to be the latest development in xtext testing. 
 http://www.xpect-tests.org/